# How can I execute a bin with yarn?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I have the following package.json and I'd like to run the bins "build" and "run":

```
{
  "name":    "simple-site",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bin": {
    "build": "./bin/build.js",
    "dev":   "./bin/dev.js"
  }
}
```

I've tried:

```
yarn run build
```

and I get

```
error Command "build" not found.
```

I've also tried:

```
yarn build
```

but the same thing happens:

```
error Command "build" not found.
```

It's propably not the right way to run bins. But then again, what is the right way to run bins with yarn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your package isn't installed.

When Yarn (and NPM) installs your package, it adds the commands under `node_modules/.bin/`, e.g. `node_modules/.bin/build`. Running `yarn build` would  (if it doesn't find a matching script in the current package) look for a `build` in this `.bin`, then traverse upwards through the filesystem, looking for other `node_modules/.bin/build`'s.

If your build script is only meant to be run while developing that specific package, add it as a script (see example [here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run/)). It would more or less look like this:

```json
{
  "name":    "simple-site",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node ./bin/build.js",
    "dev":   "node ./bin/dev.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand that. I need the bin/build.js and bin/dev.js to be available in another application.

I had expected that it's possible to somewhat run the bin files as bin files.

Of course I can run them as scripts. But what if I had a typo in my bin path or some wrong name. This is a simple example, but in my project I might end up with a few more files in the bin directory.

Comment: There should be a way to invoke the files in the bin directory the same way, they are bing invoked by the application that uses the module as a dependency.

I shouldn't have to wait until the module is installed as a dependency in another application just find out I misspelled a file name, forgot a slash, a dash and whatnot.

I'm not sure, you get my point. But I understand your answer: there is no way to check on the bin entries unless they are installed in another application.

Comment: You can have both `scripts` and `bin` present. Yarn would use the scripts when using `yarn build` within the package, while when the package is installed in another package, `yarn build` would use the `bin` version there. Small note: `build` and `dev` are very common script names for obvious reasons, so be careful with that.

Comment: yarn 3 doesn't have a `node_modules` folder.

Comment: @Catfish While that's true, it's mostly the same: Yarn in PnP mode will first look for (a built-in command, then) a script with the given name, then a bin command from one of your (direct) dependencies. For example, `yarn bin` lists `tsc` and `tsserver` when you've added `typescript` as dependency. Running `yarn bin tsc` tells us that running `yarn tsc` would actually run e.g. `.yarn/cache/typescript-patch-5b340b6a68-9.zip/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc`. Small detail is that Yarn stores references to all commands in `yarn.lock` for a fast lookup, instead of having to scan every dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Do not need relative path added:

```
{
    "name":    "simple-site",
    "version": "0.0.5",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "build.js",
      "dev":   "dev.js"
    }
}
```

The hashbang comment specifies the path to a specific JavaScript interpreter that you want to use to execute the script.

For example, helloWorld.js in ./node_modules/.bin:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("Hello world");
```